# React onClick not responding

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a newbie in react. I am not so sure why this onClick event is not responding. I am trying render a modal when icon is clicked for some reasons I am the onClick event is not responding. I have tried it in 2 ways
onClick = {()=> {handleEdit()}
onClick = {handleEdit}

I am using this NoteWidget in another component called customerProfile is I dont know if that is creating any issue.

```
import React from 'react'
import './Notewidget.scss'
import AddCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircle';
import {List, Skeleton,Divider,Modal,Input} from 'antd';
import InfinteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import {useState} from 'react';


 const Notewidget = () => {

  const [isEditing,setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const handleEdit = () => {
    console.log('button clicked');
    setIsEditing(true);
  }


  return (
    <div className='notes'>
      <div className='heading'>
      <h3 className='title'>NOTES</h3>
       <div className='icon'><AddCircleIcon onClick={() => {handleEdit()}}/></div>
      </div>
        <div className='list'
        style={{
        overflow:'auto',
        padding:'0px px',
        width:400,
        height:543
    }}
      >
       <InfinteScroll
       dataLength={data.length}
       next={data}
      size='large'
       hasMore={data.length < 5}
       loader={
        <Skeleton
        avatar
        paragraph={{
          rows:1,
        }}
        active
        />
       }
       endMessage={<Divider plain>Add Note</Divider>}>
        <List
        itemLayout="horizontal"
        dataSource={data}
        renderItem={(item)=>(
          <List.Item>
            <List.Item.Meta
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            />
          </List.Item>
        )}
        />
          </InfinteScroll>
        </div>

        <Modal
        visible={isEditing}>

        </Modal>
     

    </div>
  )
}

export default Notewidget
```

[image]

when I am clicking on the border next to notes it is working the modal is popping up

```
@import "antd/dist/antd.css";
.notes{
    
    flex:1;
    margin-right: 20px;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
     height: 650px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 1px rgba(201,201,201,0.47);
    background-color: white;

    .heading{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        h3{
            padding: 20px;
    
            .title{
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight:bolder;
                line-height: 1.2;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: rgb(50, 51, 50);
                margin: 0px 0px 20px;
                
            }
        }
    
        .icon{
          padding-top: 16px;
          padding-left: 265px;
        }

    }

    .list{
        padding: 10px;
      
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong here. `onClick={handleEdit}` would also be just fine since you are not passing any parameters. Add the on click to a different `<div>` element to see if you are using `onClick` wrong. Then if that works, probably your icon is not getting clicked (probably due to height-width issues?) If you are still stuck, please create a codesandbox example with the problem reproduced.

Comment: @SinanYaman - Please don't suggest creating the [mcve] off-site. Instead, suggest **on-site** Stack Snippets. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: As Sinan Yaman said, this looks pretty much right (in terms of the click handler), though you can change it as they indicated. Please try to reduce the problem to a [mcve] (see the link for details, it's not just to fob you off :-) ). Ideally make your [mcve] **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the way `handleEdit` is passed/called by the `onClick` handler. Are there any errors? What debugging have you done?

Comment: I will try that but then in another component I am doing the same thing with the icon it is working. I dont know why isnt this working.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sometimes it's ***a lot*** easier to provide a running code example in an external site like codesandbox since it's actually more like an IDE; importing packages is more natural. Stack snippets only get you so far before it's more work than it's worth standing up a reproducible demo. I totally agree all the relevant code should also be provided as a code snippet in the question though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The stack snippets are also woefully out of date, the latest React version it supports out-the-box is `react@16.6.3`.

Comment: @DrewReese - I use the latest React in Stack Snippets all the time. See the [instructions linked above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/), the version is easily dealt with and the steps for doing so clearly explained. The problem is people always leave things out when the example is off-site. It would be nice if they didn't, but... :-)

Comment: The issues with Stack Snippets [have long been one of my biggest problems with Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets), though. The failure to provide a half-decent environment in 2022 fair ***screams*** "we don't care about our users." :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, none of that is *that* difficult, but it's like 10 extra hoops to jump through to stand up a demo, and the sticking point for me most of the time is not being able to use the import statement and trying to figure out how to use the packages that were added via the script/CDN. If all that is needed is vanilla React, yeah, the stack snippet is pretty trivial.

Comment: @DrewReese - And if you could get people not to leave things out, then the "only" issue with off-site resources would be that they're inaccessible to some people. But they usually leave things out. Anyway, I suspect we can agree that SE **really** needs to pull their finger out. I mean, they like sponsorship deals, right? So pair up with one of the many online IDEs to put a branded version here on SO. I bet any of them would pay.

Comment: I agree with both of you on this, I created only few _on-site_ snippets, and those were done by closely following your instruction post T.J. Crowder , and as DrewReese pointed out that was not the easiest thing to do. I would personally love to see an online IDE pair up or something to make this easier.

Comment: I have updated the issue could you guys once check

Comment: You can see `onClick` works here, as per console logs. The problem is elsewhere as the error message suggests.

Comment: It is an issue of css. I have understood that but I am unable sort the issue

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things -

1. did you check the console log in developer mode?
2. Yes, the way you have told to invoke the functions are connect but there is more to it. for time-being if you are not passing any parameters to function then you should use the 2nd way [ onClick = {handleEdit}]

3.since you have attached your handler to mui Icon, that might be the reason. try putting the onClick to parent of icon i.e div like this -

```
<div className='icon' onClick={handleEdit}><AddCircleIcon/></div>
```

4.please try put some playground link (JS fiddle/codeSandbox) so that anyone can try doing changes in code.

Comment: I have tried this as well it isnt responding. I will reproduce the code and add in the link and yes I have checked the console in Inspect